# Further explanation needed for "If $f_n(x) \longrightarrow 0$ almost everywhere (a.e.) and......."

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I came across the following problem and do not know how to proceed:

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integrable functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$. Then I have to prove that
>
> "If $f_n(x) \longrightarrow 0$ almost everywhere (a.e.) and the $f_n$'s  are uniformly bounded,then $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \longrightarrow 0$".

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use bounded convergence theorem.

> Let $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions, supported on the set $E$ of finite measure and $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise on $E$. If $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded, then $$ \lim \int f_n = \int f $$

Comment: @Potato: since a.e. was mentioned in the question, i assumed familiarity with them.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I read the question too quickly. Nevermind me.